# iOS "Local" Push Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

**Hey**,

I'm looking for a way to make "local" push notifications. I can't figure out how I should do this, so I'm looking for some help. What I need is:

- a way to send a notification for a user who haven't opened the application within 24 hours. (Or that an *int* havent change)

I really hope that one of you got time to help me, thanks!

Comment: I noticied *while typing a tag for you* that ui-local-notification was a listed tag.  This makes me doubt you tried at all to find a solution for the problem before coming here.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward:

1) When the app is closed, schedule a local notification that will fire in 24 hours

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
    notification.alertBody = @"24 hours passed since last visit :(";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

2) if the app is opened (before the local notification fires), cancel the local notification

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}
```

Comment: I have a quick question:

- If I now want to check if it's working, how do I make a version that sends this notification within 30 or 10 seconds?

Comment: Just change the `60*60*24` to `30` (this is the number of seconds from `now`)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this purpose.

And  implement your [UIApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) `applicationWillTerminate` and `applicationDidEnterBackground` delegates like:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
   [self scheduleNotification];
}

 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   [self scheduleNotification];
}

 - (void)scheduleNotification
{
   UILocalNotification *locNot = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
   locNot.fireDate             = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 60 * 24];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: locNot];
}
```

When you enter to your app you need to cancel this notification. So implement `applicationDidBecomeActive` like;

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`UILocalNotification` will suit you requirements [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Pls comment downvoting? maybe I can improve the answer