# localNotification using the app last run time

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

This is my current code

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; // gets default calendar
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]]; // gets the year, month, day,hour and minutesfor today's date
    [components setHour:15];
    [components setMinute:4];

    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotification.fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Come back for more new stuff!";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

I want the fire date to be set 12hours from the app last run time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS "Local" Push Notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339052/ios-local-push-notification)

Answer (score 0):

Schedule the notification at app launch with a date like this: `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60*12]`.

You don't need to do anything with timezones or the calendar as this happens locally on the device of the user.